# join three tables in codeigniter with one to many relation

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I am doing a project in codeigniter.Here I want to join three tables

clients(id, name, email, adminId, campaignId, dateAdded, is_deleted)

campaign(id, name, adminId) and

order(id, name, cost, dateAdded, clientId).

From these tables i want to select(in between two dates) the number of clients added,campaign name and total order cost of a client.When I joined the two tables (clients and campaign) it returns the correct result.

The query I used is

```
$this->db->select('clients.id AS my_client,
    clients.name AS client_name,
    campaign.name AS campaign_name,
    DATE(clients.dateAdded) as client_date,
    COUNT(clients.id) AS num_rows');

$this->db->from('clients');
$this->db->where('clients.adminId', $adminId);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) >=', $from_date);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) <=', $to_date);
$this->db->join('campaign', 'campaign.id = clients.campaignId', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('campaign_name');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

But when I joined three tables(clients, campaign, order) it is not returning correct result.The relation between client and order is one to many.Ie one client can have more than one order.So it will not give correct value for total number of clients added between two dates.The join query I used to join three tables is

```
$this->db->select('clients.id AS my_client,
    clients.name AS client_name,
    campaign.name AS campaign_name,
    DATE(clients.dateAdded) AS client_date,
    SUM(order.cost) AS order_cost,
    COUNT(clients.id) AS num_rows');

$this->db->from('clients');
$this->db->where('clients.adminId', $adminId);
$this->db->where('clients.is_deleted', 0);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) >=', $from_date);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) <=', $to_date);
$this->db->join('campaign', 'campaign.id = clients.campaignId', 'left');
$this->db->join('order', 'order.clientId = clients.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('campaign_name');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Can anyone have some idea to do this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any results, or just not the results you were expecting?

Comment: @Gavin Yes.I got some results.But not the expected one.

Comment: The one thing I have noticed between your two queries is that you are using `clients.is_deleted = 0` on your second query, where as you're not on your first. Other than that, your query looks fine to me?

Comment: @Gavin I havent given the complete filelds from the table.Actually there is a field is_delete in the table clients.I have given only the necessary fields to execute the join query.

Comment: Ok, can you post what you are being returned (replace sensitive data with dummy values) and an example of what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I got the expected result by counting distinct client.id (COUNT(DISTINCT(clients.id))) for the number of clients added,

```
$this->db->select('clients.id AS my_client,
    clients.name AS client_name,
    campaign.name AS campaign_name,
    DATE(clients.dateAdded) AS client_date,
    SUM(order.cost) AS order_cost,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(clients.id)) AS num_rows'); //changed the code here from COUNT(clients.id) AS num_rows

$this->db->from('clients');
$this->db->where('clients.adminId', $adminId);
$this->db->where('clients.is_deleted', 0);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) >=', $from_date);
$this->db->where('DATE(clients.dateAdded) <=', $to_date);
$this->db->join('campaign', 'campaign.id = clients.campaignId', 'left');
$this->db->join('order', 'order.clientId = clients.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('campaign_name');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I dont think this is the correct way.Is there any better way to do this.Thanks for your support.